# Solving the equation $yz=y^z-2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, inequality, diophantine-equations

> ***Question:*** Let $x,y$ and $z$ be ***positive*** integers. How can we determine the positive integer solutions to the equation $$yz=y^z-2$$

The motivation here is straightforward. Surely $6=2\times 3$ and also $8=2^3$ and $9=3^2$. I wanted to "generalize" those observations by writing

\begin{align}
x&=yz\\
x+2&=y^z\\
x+3&=z^y
\end{align}

Trivially we can get to $y^z-2=x$ and after substitution we have the equation $$yz=y^z-2$$

WolframAlpha quickly spits out $y=2$ and $z=3$ as the only positive integer solutions. It also gives a "solution for the variable z" as

$$z=-{yW\left(-y^{-1-{2\above 1.5pt y}} \right)-2\log{y}\above 1.5pt y\log{y}} $$

where $W(a)$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Following the Wiki link leads me to think a possible start is to consider $$-t=x+{2\above 1.5pt y} $$ and we can now transform our equation into $$ty^t=-{1\above 1.5pty}y^{-{2\above 1.5pt y }}$$ which apparently yields the solution for $z$ written above. But I am still not clear how WolframAlpha explicitly determined that $z=3$.

Comment: There's no $x$ in your equation. And using the $W$ function isn't going to be effective for finding integer solutions.

Comment: $yz=y^z-2$ means that you want $y$ a factor of $2$. So you want to solve $2z=2^{z}-2$, or $z=2^{z-1}-1$. It's east to show that $2^{z-1}$ grows too fast to have any solutions for $n$ large. In particular, you can show that easily show $2^{z-1}>1+z$ inductively for $z>3$.

Comment: Expression 
$z(y,n)=\frac{ -y\operatorname{W}_{n} \left(-{y}^{-1-2/y}\ln y\right) -2\,\ln y }{y\ln y}$
has two real branches (for $n=0$ and $n=-1$),
and $z(2,-1)$ is exactly `3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma(I)**: Let $3 \leq y$, then we have:
$$2y < y^2-2.$$

**Proof**: $3 \leq y$, so we must have:

$$2 \leq (y-1) 
\Longrightarrow 
3 < 4 \leq (y-1)^2 
\Longrightarrow 
3 < y^2-2y+1 
\Longrightarrow 
2y < y^2-2 . 
$$

---

**Lemma(II)**: 
Let $3 \leq y$ be any fixed arbitrary integer 
and let $2 \leq z$, then we have: 
$$  \color{Red}{yz < y^z-2}  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \text{(II)}   .   $$

**Proof**: 
Let $y$ be an  arbitrary (but fixed) integer 
greater or equal than $3$. 
We will prove the lemma by induction on $z$.

$z=2$; which is done by **Lemma(I)**.

Now suppose that the **Lemma(II)** is true for $z=k$; 
then we will show it for  $z=k+1$. 
Only notice that:

$$ \color{Blue}{y} < zy+2 < y^z < (y-1)y^z = 
\color{Blue}{y^{z+1}-y^z}
\ 
; $$

adding this last inequality by inequlaity (II) we get:

$$ y(z+1)= \color{red}{yz}+ \color{Blue}y <  
\color{Red}{y^z-2} +   \color{Blue}{y^{z+1}-y^z} = 
y^{z+1}-2  .$$

---

**Lemma(III)**: 
Let $y=2$ 
and let $4 \leq z$, then we have: 
$$  \color{Red}{2z < 2^z-2}  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \text{(III)}   .   $$

**Proof**:
We will prove the lemma by induction on $z$.

$z=4$; is trivial.

Now suppose that the **Lemma(III)** is true for $z=k$; 
then we will show it for  $z=k+1$. 
Only notice that:

$$ \color{Blue}{2} < 2z+2 < 2^z = 
\color{Blue}{2^{z+1}-2^z}
\ 
; $$

adding this last inequality by inequlaity (III) we get:

$$ 2(z+1)= \color{red}{2z}+ \color{Blue}2 <  
\color{Red}{2^z-2} +   \color{Blue}{2^{z+1}-2^z} = 
2^{z+1}-2  .$$

---

---

---

---

**First Case**: Let $3 \leq y$:

- $2 \leq z$; which is impossible by **Lemma(II)**.
- If $z=1$; then we have $y.1=y^1-2$, 
  which is obviously impossible again!

**Second Case**: Let $y=2$:

- $4 \leq z$; which is impossible by **Lemma(III)**.
- $z=3$; which gives the solution $\color{Green}{(y,z)=(2,3)}.$
- $z=2$; which does not give any solution!
- $z=1$; which does not give any solution again!

**Third case**: Let $y=1$:

- in this case we have: $1.z=1^z-2$; 
  which does not have a solution in $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y$ and $z$ be positive integers such that $yz=y^z-2$. Then also
$$y(y^{z-1}-z)=2,$$
which shows that $y$ divides $2$, so either $y=1$ or $y=2$. Correspondingly we get
$$1^{z-1}-z=2\qquad\text{ and }\qquad 2^{z-1}-z=1,$$
and the former clearly has no integral solutions. The latter is equivalent to
$$2^{z-1}=z+1,$$
which is easily seen to have $z=3$ as the only integral solution.